# Unresponsive Certification Support - any idea how to contact them?

Tags: case, certification, support

I'm trying to start a Salesforce certification exam since last week but I did run into several technical problems with the Sentinel App and biometric identification. The basic issues I have resolved on my own, but I'm still stuck. The remaining issue is that at the biometric login my picture is not recognized.

The KRYTERION support did his very best and finally pointed me to Salesforce support, since KRYTERION can't reset biometric data or re-schedule an exam more than one day into the future.

At http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case I have already logged two cases last week and again two cases this week. As an unfortunate the support is totally unresponsive. I only have received the automatic responder after the new case - since that nothing. At least my email has proven correct.

So I tried to contact our partner support. Response there was very quick and I started to feel better - but then they simply closed down the case and pointed me back to http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case - which stays unresponsive.

As a matter of fact I already spent two times $200 for not being able to simply start the exam. Now in a few hours my current schedule will expire again. I can't reschedule it further into the future via the Webassessor myself - today 23:45 is the ultimate point. If cert-support stays unresponsive it seems that I have wasted $400 for nothing.

My questions are:

- Is it typical that the response time of cert-support is > 2 days?
- Does anyone have an idea on how to get motion into unresponsive certification cases?
- It seems that there is no phone number to call, right? Or is there any?
- Any secret communication path or any idea form the Saleforce people around here?

Any help or ideas are welcome!

Comment: Try posting on Twitter using #askforce and see if that doesn't catch someone's eye who might be in a position to assist you with this issue (or knows someone who is).

Comment: Salesforce.com usually compensate errors like this, so it's likely you'll get at least some of your money back if you explain the issue when they finally do contact you. As an aside, you can always email Marc Benioff as a last resort. I hear he's very responsive with serious matters such as neglect.

Comment: @crmprogdev good idea, will try #askforce

Comment: @sfdcfox will keep Marc as a last resort. I think for now looking for help here, on twitter and possibly linkedin might be sufficient. But thanks for this idea.

Comment: I've heard things posted to Twitter tend to eventually filter to Benioff's attention if not resolved. Good luck on this one.

Comment: I had the same issue. It took a week for them to get back to me. They allowed me to reschedule the exam. They said they reset my biometric profile so that I could take a picture but they did not say how. There is no button available in my webassessor profile. So now I am waiting again for them to get back to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What actually helped, was to post into the Certification Group of the Partner Community. I got a very quick and nice response from Kari Lucio and right now they have refunded all of my prior expenses. Only waiting on the bio-reset, which should be easy, I guess.

**update:** bio-reset is done, too.

Thanks Salesforce, well done!

Comment: I am glad you situation was resolved but I have to take exception to the "Well Done" comment. How it jumping through hoops to find an alternate channel of communication due to no response from the first line communication a "well done".

Comment: Hi @Eric - the "well done" belongs to their handling of the cases after things came into motion yesterday. It was very fast and very cooperative.

Comment: Understood - Was just frustrated with similar recurring issues with support. Thank god we have amazing developers to support their product here on SFSE because without it SF would not be where it is. We are the ones holding up their product....I an a firm believer that anyone with a certification from SF should have access to SF Support beyond the "free" support

Comment: Hi @Eric - I know exactly what you mean. For me the most crucial thing is not having developer support as partner and certified individual. What we do here and elsewhere should be at least worth enough, to be allowed to report the bugs. The SF forums do not work and I gave up on them. I would differ between permanent support flaws and temporary support overload. I hope my issue here was the latter type.