# Certification exam got disconnected and in webassessor it is showing that exam got suspended

Tags: certification

While giving my salesforce developer certification exam it is stopped in the middle and in the chat they mentioned to switch the camera direction and while performing that action my exam got closed and I'm unable to launch again and it is showing that exam got suspended please contact your program manager for rescheduling your assessment.

I emailed my situation to certification@salesforce.com and I got case number but there is no update from the last 2 days how can I reach out to them for a quick response.

Comment: [This might help you](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67516/unresponsive-certification-support-any-idea-how-to-contact-them)  to reach them.

Answer (score 2):

Any issue/question related to Webassesor should be raised to their support team:

> **Have a question?**
>
> Please visit our knowledge base to find answers to
>   common questions about the Salesforce.com Certification program. For
>   additional assistance, open a case with the Salesforce.com
>   Certification team.

the support link can be found support link [here](https://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case)